# How to return LOW VALUES HEX '00' in sql statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, hex, utl-file

I need to write into file (in the middle of the string) a LOW VALUES HEX'00'.

I could do it using package utl_file using the next code `utl_file.put_raw(v_file, hextoraw('000000'))`. But I may do it only in the beginning and end of file, not in the middle of string.

So, my question is: how to write a LOW VALUES HEX'00' in the select statement.
I tried some variants like

```
Select ‘blablabla’ Q, hextoraw('000000'), ‘blablabla’ w from dual;
```

save it into `.dat` file, then open it in hex-editor but the result was different when using utl_file.

Could anybody  (if it's possible) write a correct sql statement.

Comment: What do you mean by "LOW VALUES HEX"? Are you talking about a non-printable byte? Can you give an example? Also how does this relate to SQL? ie. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I need to create a .dat file which contents a lot of string uploaded into it from oracle db. And I hav it now: firstly i created a middle_table, after that I use utl_file to write a file in the directory, and afteк use a javascript to proceed thу file.                In that .dat file i  have HEX'00' symbols like om the screenshot [link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/25164865/file.jpg) (i craeted a table ipload it on the disk and processed by javascript, it is opened in n++ in normal mode, not in hex-mode).

Comment: So i need to create this file using only pl\sql functionality. And my question is, in other words, how to put in the table, which after will upload on the disk by utl_file, HEX'00' symbols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to add a null/binary zero to your output. If so, you can just use `chr(0)`.

eg. `utl_file.putf(l_file, 'This is a binary zero' || chr(0));`

Looking at that in a hex editor will show you:

```
00000000  54 68 69 73 20 69 73 20  61 20 62 69 6e 61 72 79  |This is a binary|
00000010  20 7a 65 72 6f 00 0a                              | zero..|
```

Comment: also i use blob type for fields in my table from which i upload data to the disk.